# Detect if Crosshair is present/visible - TradingView Lightweight Charts

Tags: javascript, lightweight-charts

Is there a way to detect whether the crosshair is currently visible/shown on the chart? I see these options that set crosshair settings, but no boolean/API to detect whether the crosshair is currently shown. Any ideas? Should I simply detect using javascript and `divElement.getBoundingClientRect();` on mouseMove/touchMove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property to track that on the chart object, but you can track it yourself using `subscribeCrosshairMove` event handler, when the `param.point` become null that means that the cursor is out of the chart, and when the user points to the chart again the point x/y will get some values.

```
chart.subscribeCrosshairMove(param => {
  console.log(param.point)
})
```

Comment: hey @Dmitry,

I am using LWC in my android app. How to detect if user release his touch from chart.

for example: User is touch & hold on chart and swipe left to right. If user release this touch, can we detect it?